# How to be assured servlet response has been received

Tags: servlets

Is there a way to be assured that the recipient of a Java EE servlet response has received it (i.e. TCP ACK'd the whole thing)?

Answer (score 0):

Put a try-catch on `IOException` while manipulating/writing to the response and flush/close it yourself. If it isn't been thrown, then the entire response has successfully been sent.

To get a step further, you could do an `instanceof` check on servlet-container specific `IOException` type such as `ClientAbortException` in case of Tomcat and clones. This indicates that the client has aborted the connection by itself (e.g. by pressing Esc in browser or navigating away while the response isn't fully returned.